# sql join problem

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

hy!
I have 2 tables. The structure is the above:

students

```
 idStudent     name    age    job     code
 1      john    18     student        1
 2      john    19     programmer     1
 3      john    18     developer      2
 4      mark    18     student        3
 5      mark    19     programmer     1
```

infos

```
id     address    tel     code
1      fdsf      00232    1 
2       gffdfd    322     1
 3      dsdd     1833     2 
 4      gffg     43333    3
 5      fff      1933    1
```

I want to obtain a table with the structure:

```
   idStudent     name    age    address   tel   code
   1             john    18                     1
   3             john    18                     2
   4              mark    18                   3
```

So what I want to do is to obtain a table with unique code and all the other fields to be filled with the first or last (it has no importance for me) data which appear in the table. I don`t want to have duplicated code fields, this is important for me.

Comment: why is the `code` field duplicated in both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select S.IdStudent, MIN(Name) Name, MIN(Age) Age, MIN(Address) Address, MIN(Tel) Tel, MIN(Code) Code
FROM Students S Inner Join Info I  ON S.IDStudent = I.Id
group by S.IdStudent
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to obtain the info in each table for each student, this is a simple JOIN Query:

```
SELECT e.idStudent, e.name, e.age, i.address, i.tel, e.code
FROM students e
INNER JOIN infos i ON e.idEstudent=i.id
```

If you have duplicated information, you can use a GROUP BY clausule to obtain the info grouped and MIN or MAX to obtain the values of each field you don't group.

**EDITED to take in account the comment from user599977:**

From your comment I imagine you have duplicated rows in info?, if that's the case you can do something like:

```
SELECT e.idStudent, max(e.name), max(e.age), max(i.address), max(i.tel), max(e.code)
FROM students e
INNER JOIN infos i ON e.idEstudent=i.id
GROUP BY e.idStudent
```

But I will recommend you to filter for some more predictable field, like last introduced record or something similar.

For example:

```
SELECT e.idStudent, e.name, e.age, i.address, i.tel, e.code
FROM students e
INNER JOIN infos i ON e.idEstudent=i.id
WHERE i.loadDate= (
    SELECT max(loadDate)
    FROM infos
    WHERE id=e.idStudent
)
```

Assuming you have some column with a timestamp or some data that allows you to determine which row is the last that the user entered.

Comment: I tried that but I`ve got code 1 three times...because the information from the other fields it was different...i want to obtain it only once